# Android: ViewHolder concepts

Tags: android, listview

I'm realizing CustomAdapter for my ListView and using ViewHolder class.
My code was:

```
     if (convertView == null) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_item, null);
        viewHolder.ivCard = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ivCardImage);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }


    final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
```

but my colleagues said that my variant can shows list items incorrectly and corrected it to

```
ViewHolder holder;
if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_item, null);
        holder.ivCard = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ivCardImage);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else {
         holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
```

I understand that their code is the best practice, but can it really affect to list items mapping?

Comment: Yes , It will surely affects on the items mapping. Because the ViewHolder always inflates the layout once as many times getView method is called. But if the layout is already inflated then it will going to use its id's to access it.

Comment: But in both variants the ViewHolder will gets from view tag.

Comment: Yes ,, Its affects the mapping. Please try scrolling the listview or put the screen in landscape mode. U can understand the diffrence

Comment: I'm scrolling ListView and all items shows correctly.

Comment: Can you please explain what the difference?

Answer (score 0):

No, your code doesn't affect to list items mapping.